# Polymer 1.0 hidden$="{{show}}" not working

Tags: polymer-1.0

Im trying to create a toggleable menu, but for some reason the hidden attribute won't work. It won't work for either value so I don't think its a data binding problem.

I'm using this method in other parts of my project and in other javascript liberies and frameworks it never gets any more complex, so I can't see what i'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">


<dom-module id="user-account-menu">

    <template>

        <style>
            img {
                width: 72px;
                height: 72px;
            }
            paper-menu {
                position: absolute;
                right: 15px;
                width: 200px;
                background: #A3A3A3;
            }
        </style>


        <firebase-auth
            id="auth"
            signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
            user="{{user}}">
        </firebase-auth>


        <!-- start the account dropdon -->
        <div>
            <img src="{{computePhotoURL()}}">

            <paper-menu hidden$="{{show}}">
              <paper-item>This is a menu item</paper-item>
              <paper-item>[[show]]</paper-item>
            </paper-menu>
        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'user-account-menu',

            properties: {
                show: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    value: true
                }
            },

            computePhotoURL: function() {
                // get the users photo, if one doesn't exist, 
                // get the default user avatar
                var photo;

                try {
                    photo = this.user.photoURL;
                    return photo;
                } catch(err) {
                    return 'https://developers.google.com/experts/img/user/user-default.png';
                }
            },
        });
    </script>

</dom-module>
```

update (css of paper-menu from dom):

```
element.style {
}
<style>…</style>
paper-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #A3A3A3;
}
<style>…</style>
:host {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #212121;
```

Comment: Did you investigate the DOM and check whether the `hidden` attribute gets added removed?

Comment: It does have one *<paper-menu role="menu" tabindex="0" hidden="">*

Comment: And when you toggle the value to get it removed, does it get removed?

Comment: The value changes but nothing is hidden or shown but togging does remove and show the hidden attribute in the DOM

Comment: Changing the value doesn't do anything. `hidden` is a boolean attribute and only gets disabled when it is removed. `hidden="false"` and `hidden="true"` are exactly the same thing.

Comment: When true, i have: *<paper-menu role="menu" tabindex="0" hidden="">*, when false, i have: *<paper-menu role="menu" tabindex="0">*

Comment: Manually adding a false or true to the attribute via chrome developer tools has no change.

Comment: What browser are you using? Is some CSS `display` setting applied to this element?

Comment: Google Chrome, latest update

Comment: Yeah theres is a display:block inherited from :host, and removing that properties looks like it will fix it

Comment: How can I set the style for the component so that it has no value for display?

Comment: Check the devtools first if there is some CSS that applies a value for `display`.

Comment: the css I have is is the question

Comment: The `display` block probably breaks the hidden. I'd suggest using `template dom-if` instead or add/remove a `hidden` class and a CSS rule `.hidden { display: none; }`.

Comment: There is, it comes from the styling in the paper-menu.html file, removing it fixes the problem, is their i way i can override the property in my new user-account-menu component as not to edit the source of a imported component.

Comment: Removing that style probably breaks the component. Use rather one of my suggestions in my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `display: block` setting of the `paper-menu` component breaks the `hidden` functionality.

Using the `hidden` attribute is considered bad practice anyway because exactly this issue you just run into. It conflicts with the `display` setting.

I'd suggest using

- `<template dom-if="..."`
  or
- add/remove a hidden class and a CSS rule `.hidden { display: none; }` (this also works in IE9 which doesn't recognize the `hidden` attribute.

Comment: This works `<template is="dom-if" if="{{show}}"> <paper-menu> ...`. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Another option is just to add this to your styles:

```
<style>
  [hidden] {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: What would be needed for that to be applied? <some-element hidden>?

Comment: It fixed my problem, thank you very much. But how would I avoid the problem? What I mean is that the `!important` is overriding a previous `display` for `hidden`, so how would I set the `display: none` in the root of the problem? I say that because I'm not totally comfortable with `!important`s, I feel that I'll have problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `?` from the `hidden?="{{show}}"`